# Loading large SAS data into R/Python

Tags: python, r, io, sas

Currently, I have a few 50 GB SAS data files (`sas7bdat`) and I would like to switch previous SAS code to an open source tool like R or Python. The biggest issue is how to deal with those giant files... I tried to export one 50 GB file into a `CSV` file then used `fread` in R to load it. However, it crushed during the file loading. So I am wondering what are the best way to handle this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have sufficient RAM to keep such a big object in memory? If not, you need to look at R packages for out-of-memory data. See this task view: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: @Roland I only have 16GB and yes I am afraid not enough to load everything into memory...

Comment: Consider putting the data into a database like SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some things to take into consideration:

- Uncompressed SAS files are huge. 50GB is probably <10GB as a CSV.
- R is a memory hog. You won't be able to do this with vanilla R.
- Python is actually quite efficient with memory when handling lists (i.e., records), it might just fit/work depending on what you want to do.
- Neither provide out-of-the-box parallelism, it needs an R package/python module. So by default, it will be slow even if it fits memory.
- You can to some extent evade the everything-in-memory issue in Python by making sure you use iterables everywhere instead of turning everything everywhere all the time into lists.

But a convenient solution for you would be to make use of Python together with **PySpark** (or R with SparkR, but the former is more mature at the moment):

- Not everything needs to be in memory at once
- You get parallelism out-of-the-box
- If you are 'one of those people' using proc sql everywhere, you can leverage Spark SQL for easy re-use of your work.

Have a look at the the project: https://spark.apache.org

Comment: Thanks so much for the resourceful reply! I will look into PySpark. In addition, the converted CSV file is not small ~30 GB ...